# Automatically update DB cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm currently making an e commerce website using cakephp. 
An article can be activated or disabled (bool). I put a validity date for an article and I'd like to automatically disable the article if outdated.

What is the best way to do it? With a SQL Event and trigger? Or can I write an event function in Cakephp and how?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible in a php function. I mean, automatically call a function to set active to 0 when vality_date < now.

Comment: Best is subjective, why don't you just add a "is this article still valid?" check to wherever you use it, and if it isn't update the record. Or just add a condition to where you find articles, or run that sql command whenever you feel like it (cron every day, hour or minute) or etc. The question is too broad because you can deal with that many, many ways.

Comment: A checkbox is already done but it's manual. The condition to where I find articles is done too:the outdated articles aren't shown. But the article isn't desactived so we still can see it with the URL. Ok I'm going to do a SQL event...

Comment: `But the article isn't desactived so we still can see it with the URL.` That's precisely where I would expect the check I mentioned to be implemented.

Comment: Ok I'm going to try something, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you could just do this in the controller for the action which displays an article.

This is very general untested code just to show the idea.

**app/Controller/ArticlesController.php**

```
public function view($id) {

    // First get the requested article's validity date
    $this->Article->id = $id;
    $validity = $this->Article->field('validity_date');

    // See if the date has expired
    if ($validity < date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) {
        throw new NotFoundException(); // Trigger 404 page
    }

    // Otherwise you're all good, so continue with showing the article...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll try something similar. I'll post it here if it's a success!